# If deployment via SFDX fails, then no components are deployed?

Tags: salesforcedx, deployment, deployment-error

If I will do deployment to my scratch org and I have "Deployment Failed" (because of 1 failing component), then it means that no component was deployed?

Is there a way to deploy all components that passed without that 1 failing component?

Answer (score 3):

The VS Code extension uses an all-or-none approach. If you want to allow partial saves, you can use the CLI by using the terminal command:

```
sfdx force:source:deploy -p force-app -o -g
```

Where -o ignores errors and -g ignores warnings.